# SyntaxError + Invariant Violation

Tags: react-native, react-native-hermes

React Native 0.66.2 works perfectly without [Hermes](https://hermesengine.dev/).

When I'm enabling Hermes `:hermes_enabled => true` the packager doesn't happy.

I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR  SyntaxError: 5:1:invalid statement encountered., js engine: hermes
ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
      This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native., js engine: hermes
```

[image]

[image]

I tried to link all native libraries again (as says [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26687)) but with no luck :(

Any help will be super welcome

Answer (score 0):

After enabling hermes you have to clean and rebuild the project if it is possible.Otherwise it causes some errors. In order to clean you can use the following commands.

first, go to android by typing " cd android " from your root project directory and run the following command

```
./gradlew clean
```

You can also reset react native and npm cache by using following commands.

```
react-native start --reset-cache
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

Last , try to clean build files from android directory and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 0):

- Delete your `node_modules` directory and run `npm  i`
- For Android 
  `cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd ..` 
  (windows) `cd android && gradlew clean && cd ..` 
  For iOS
  `cd ios && rm -rf Pods && pod cache clean --all && pod install && cd ..`
- Run `react-native start --reset-cache`

Comment: Come on man, I already clean my mac with bleach... Of course I did all the above but with no luck :/

Answer (score 0):

For this error try this

- in your project locate the `*gradle.properties*`
- in that file make the changes below
  Use this property to enable or disable the Hermes JS engine.
  If set to false, you will be using JSC instead.
- by default this should be true
  **hermesEnabled=false**
- try making it false